# avoid break when choosing item from list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Considering a list, and wanting to select the first item from it that is not in a second list, and then stop searching, what is the most efficient way to do this (without breaking):

```
aa = [11,22,33,44,55,66]
bb = [11,12,22,23,33,34,88,66]

for x in aa:
    if x not in bb:
        bb.append(x)
        break
print(f'{aa} \n{bb}')
```

Like this but in a efficient way.

Comment: Well, `break` is not really inefficient or anything... If what you want is a more efficient solution, maybe using a set to track the elements in `bb` would help more.

Comment: @ImperishableNight break is very inefficient for a processor, it makes the core lose all the predicted pre-loaded instructions since it encountered an unexpected result, which results in a big number of clocks lost

Comment: And you think that won't happen if you don't use break?

Comment: Normally there is a way to work around your code that makes it considerable faster, I'm just trying to learn correct practices to improve my coding in general.

Comment: Well, in the case of python, if you find yourself worrying about things like `break` with good reason, then the answer is usually to not use pure python. (If you are curious, take a took at [Cython](https://cython.org/).)

Comment: But really, usually there are much bigger things to worry about. For example, I strongly suspect that when you try your code on a larger data set, the `x not in bb` would be what takes the most time in total.

Comment: Possibly, maybe numpy would help?

Comment: In this case, or in many cases involving the `in` operator, using a `dict` or `set` is what you should try to do. I guess numpy can also help, but it would just be a constant factor. (Admittedly, in the case of Python, the constant factor is usually very large.)

Comment: The code in the accepted answer is two times slower than your code btw, if you remove appending. (at least for the given data)

Comment: @Georgy It is indeed a bit slower if I remove the print. rip

Comment: Could you provide more background on what you really are trying to achieve? I feel like you could be having an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). An example close to your real case would be helpful. I doubt that it's `break` that will be a bottleneck. (Related: [Is premature optimization really the root of all evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil))

Comment: There is no X. Just premature optimization :)

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way is to use `next` on a generator:

```
next((x for x in aa if x not in bb), 'Not found')
# 44
```

Answer (score 1):

```
aa = [11,22,33,44,55,66]
bb = [11,12,22,23,33,34,88,66]
set_=set()
for i in bb:
set_.add(i)
ans=-1;
for x in aa[::-1]:
    if x not in set_:
        ans=x
print(ans)
```

Comment: rather than using in on array you should use sets for efficiency purpose

Answer (score 0):

You could use set subtraction

```
>>> not_in = set(aa) - set(bb)
>>> list(not_in)[0] if not_in else 'Not found'
44
```